# Updating local datum to latest ITRF?

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, cors

I have read that Australia is updating its local reference frame.

If a small territory has a complete CORS GNSS network aligned to ITRF2000, does it need to update the CORS network to the latest ITRF2014?